# How to integrate speech notification instead of default notification tone in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Enable speech notification
How to integrate speech notification instead of default notification tone in react native,i.e a voice should read the body of the push notification(Google speech) recieved by the device.I have used custom sound for push notification But I need to integrate speech notification instead of custom sound in react native Android.When a payment is recieved by the user he is notified by a push notification so I want it to be read like a speech notification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.